# Faker.fake() does not work if input string has any params

Tags: javascript, faker

I am trying to implement some data generation with fakejs, but `faker.fake` does not work if my template has any params here is the results:

```
const c = faker.fake('{{random.number({ min: 0, max: 10, precision: 1 })}}'); //does not work, getting NaN
const z = faker.fake('{{date.between("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31")}}'); //does not work, getting 'invalid date'
```

However this works:

```
const a = faker.fake('{{random.number}}'); //works
const b = faker.random.number({ min: 0, max: 10, precision: 1 }); //works

const x = faker.date.past(); // works
const y = faker.fake('{{date.past}}'); // works
```

Any idea how to fix? I am using fakerjs version 4.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faker could not parse the parameters that it requires to be in JSON. So the parameters have to be in double quotes.

It doesn't log warnings about it, just assumes it's a string ([fake](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/master/lib/fake.js) function part below):

```js
try {
  params = JSON.parse(parameters)
} catch (err) {
  // since JSON.parse threw an error, assume parameters was actually a string
  params = parameters;
}
```

This worked for me.

```js
faker.fake('{{random.number({ "min": 0, "max": 10, "precision": 1 })}}');
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828202/faker-fake-does-not-handle-date-between ?