# Faker.fake does not handle date.between

Tags: javascript, faker

I have a template like `"{{date.between("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31")}}"` I am passing that to [faker.fake](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/be8cd96541ba277941f4489fba27fc96296ed15c/lib/date.js#L64) function but it is giving `Invalid Date`

`faker.fake("{{date.between("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31")}}") // returns Invalid date`

also was trying that `faker.fake("{{date.between({"from": "2015-01-01", "to": "2015-12-31"})}}")` but does not work anyway.

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: `faker.fake("{{date.between("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31")}}")` should be a syntax error, not Invalid Date; ditto with the JSON version below it. Are you sure your quotes look like that?

Comment: You use this way with a function what require more than 1 params. The `faker.js` use .call (instead of .apply) on toplevel to bind parameters. Issue link https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/643 , https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/blob/be8cd96541ba277941f4489fba27fc96296ed15c/lib/fake.js#L93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems faker.js has a logic bug regarding multiple parameters in a template ([issue](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/643)), so indeed you cannot do this. However, this works:

```
faker.date.between("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31");
```

Comment: I can not use that method directly, all my templates like `{{date.between("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31")}}` are defined like a strings so I have to use `faker.fake`

Comment: That's unfortunate. As I said, templates currently simply cannot handle multiple parameters.